Can this method ever throw an exception?
Consider:
template <typename T>
struct S
{
    auto Value() const
    {
        return value;
    }

    T value;
};

Can Value() ever throw an exception? Why or why not? If not, is it safe to mark this method as noexcept ?
What I fundamentally don't understand is whether return value; is something that can ever throw an exception.

You return a value, which means the value needs to be copied. If T have a copy-constructor, it might throw an exception.

The way you deal with this is to write noexcept(std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<T>).

@Someprogrammerdude but calling Value itself never leads to a copy right?

@Honey return by value does lead to a copy.

@PasserBy that is exactly my confusion. Calling Value itself doesn't lead to a copy. So why do I need to check for is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v?

@wohlstad what if there is copy-elision?

"what if there is copy-elision" there won't be in this case, and in the cases that would, you'd be moving (except there's some weirdness pre C++20).

@Honey the content of the member value would still have to be copy (or moved) into the target object that called Value(). This will be done by way of a constructor that might throw.

If you're asking about exceptions in conjunction with copy-elision, put it in the question, not as comments.

https://godbolt.org/z/PxWKMMd8b

On a more general note, don't waste your time trying to figure out things like noexcept unless you have a reason for it. It's rather error-prone, as you can see, and the compiler can't verify it (contrary to let's say an override). And in cases where the compiler CAN verify it, it can obviously see it and possibly use it for optimization purposes even if you didn't specify it...

Value() might throw an exception and therefore you should not mark it as noexcept.
This might happen since Value() returns a T object by value.
This means a copy will be made and the copy constructor of T might throw. The compiler will generate the copy istructions in the method body.
Copy-ellision is not relevant because value is a member, not a local or a temporary.
But even if was relevant, it does not change that.
The content of the value member would anyway to be copied (or moved) into the target object that called the method. This would be done by way of executing the relevant constructor of T - copy or move - or assignment operator which might throw.
It does not matter if the return value is actually assigned to a variable, as you can see in the demo below.
Demo - courtesy of @joergbrech.

please help me understand this. Consider the following contexts:
auto s = S{};
First context is this:
auto var = s.Value();
and second:
s.Value();
In both cases, the mere invocation of Value() doesn't cause an exception, it is the assignment statement which causes the exception. In case of copy-elision, the entirey of the statement auto var = s.Value(); is the cause of the exception, not s.Value();

@Honey please see the Godbolt demo I added. In your comment above the member value would need to be transfered somehow into var. As I explained this is done by executing a constructor of ComplexType. Even just s.Value(); triggers the exception as you can see in the demo, since the compiler will generate code for executing the constructor.

There can be no copy elision in the return statement, since the value returned is a member variable, not a local or temporary. There will be a copy in the function body, so any exception thrown will originate from within the function.
